# IPython fails to load win32api

Tags: winapi, ipython

I'm running Python 2.7 on windows and I've installed the [pywin extension here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

Having done so, if I launch a normal python shell, I can import win32api perfectly.

If I do the same on IPython, I get this :

```
In [1]: import win32api
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\Windows\system32\<ipython console> in <module>()

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
In [2]:
```

Why would it work in a normal python shell, but not IPython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and found a solution for my problem [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/reference/win32ext.html). Apparently it's a conflict between *pythoncom24.dll* and *pywintypes24.dll*.

Look in your root Python install folder. If you find these two DLLs there, move them to *\Python24\Lib\site-packages\win32* instead. This should fix your import conflict.

Alternately, you can control the imports explicitly. Add the following to your script in this order:

```
import pywintypes
import pythoncom
import win32api
```

Comment: The PC that I had this issue on failed last Christmas and I haven't re-installed iPython as a result! I'll have to give it another try to confirm if this works for me, but marking this as the correct answer in the mean time. Thanks.